# How do I efficiently find the n smallest elements in a list?

Tags: f#, heap, priority-queue

Finding the n smallest elements in a `list<float>` can be done by sorting the list and selecting the n smallest elements. But it also can be done more efficiently using heaps. I found several implementations of heaps for F# but no examples of how to use them for this purpose. My two stumbling blocks were:

1) I could not find a way to create a heap from a list. All implementations I have seen provide a way to create an empty heap and have an `insert` method. Should I create an empty heap and insert items one by one? That looks slow, which would defeat the purpose.

2) No implementation has a nLargest or nSmallest method like, for example, this Python code:

```
from heapq import nlargest
lst = [9,1,6,4,2,8,3,7,5]
nlargest(3, lst) # Gives [9,8,7]
```

Is there a simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you have an array, you can heapify an array in O(N) time, but the F# `list` type is a linked-list data structure, for which the heapify algorithm would be O(N^2) time since heapify relies on O(1) random access by index to its array. So your two options are: 1) convert your list into an array (one O(N) operation) and heapify it (a second O(N) operation), then get the 3 smallest elements (3 O(log N) operations). Or 2) just sort the list (O(N log N)) and then grab the 3 first elements from it (3 O(1) operations). Unless you expect your list to be HUGE, I'd say don't worry about it: just sort.

Comment: @rmunn  Thanks. But just in case, how would I heapify the array and get the smallest elements?

Comment: See https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/DemoHeapify.pdf for a visual demo and http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/cscB63h/w07/lectures/tut02.txt for some pseudocode. Briefly, start with the array, and from the last element to the first, you make sure that it's smaller than its two heap children. If not, swap it with the smaller child, and repeat that process at the smaller child. And since the rightmost half of the array has no heap children, you can actually start at `array.Length / 2` and go down to index 0. Algorithm analysis has shown that this takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you don't really need to use a heap for this.  See, e.g., [Jon Skeet's old post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early/) on how to implement quick sort to yield the sorted sequence without performing all the work up front.  (Unfortunately there's some unrelated exposition in the post, because it is just one part of a long series on re-implementing LINQ-to-objects)

Answer (score 1):

How to rearrange an array into a binary heap:

Starting at the middle of the array and moving backwards, sift each element down in the heap. For example, suppose you have an array, `a`, that has length `n`. The following will do it:

```
for i = n/2 downto 0
    siftDown(i);
```

And the `siftDown` method:

```
siftDown(int index)
{
    while (index < n/2)
    {
        // find the smallest child
        int ixChild = (ix * 2) + 1;
        if (ixChild < n-1 && a[ixChild] > n[ixChild + 1])
        {
            ixChild = ixChild + 1;
        }
        // if the item is <= the smallest child, we're done
        if (a[i] < a[ixChild]) break;

        // otherwise, swap with the smallest child
        swap(i, ixChild);

        // and do it again
        i = ixChild;
    }
}
```

Another way to select the `k` smallest items in a list is to use [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), which is basically the Quicksort partitioning method. This has the advantage of being O(n), which will typically be faster than using a heap. When the algorithm is finished the `k` smallest items are at the front of the array but they're not sorted.

Finally, you might consider using a [Pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap) rather than a binary heap if you want to use the heap selection method. Pairing heap has O(1) insert, and O(log n) removal. Plus, it should be pretty easy to implement in F# from the example on the Wikipedia page.